# Binding values to fields in Vaadin

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, vaadin

I am trying to display a JPA entity I fetch from the DB in bunch of TextField items in my View

```
Binder<Person> binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>();
binder.forField(nameField)
.withValidator(
    name -> name.length() >= 3,
    "Name must contain at least three characters")
.bind(Person::getName, Person::setName);

binder.forField(id)
    // Shorthand for requiring the field to be non-empty
    .asRequired("Every employee must have an ID")
    .bind(Person::getID, Person::setID);

 ....
Person person = personService.getPerson(key);
binder.readBean(person);// <-- Tried this
binder.bindInstanceFields(person); //< -- tried this
```

What finally gets displayed is just the ID. I have a half dozen other fields that I have not mentioned here for sake of brevity. I can print them in logs, I can see them in the debugger, but they refuse to show up in the TextField. All the TextFields are added in the layout, just to answer any doubts.
Also tried explicit calls to `setValue` on the TextField. It doesn't seem to matter. Nothing gets displayed. I understand the use case is for binder is to capture the bean values for persistence, but how do the fields get displayed? This view provides another button for use in the next view I am attempting to route, so the primary use for this View is just plain display the Person bean.

Answer (score 2):

Answers for you.

First, you need to bind the fields before reading the bean. `Binder#readBean` as stated by documentation is populating the **bound** fields. Naturally the fields not yet bound, will not get populated.

```
Person person = personService.getPerson(key);
binder.bindInstanceFields(form);
binder.readBean(person);
```

Also note, that in order to find the fields, the Binder#bindInstanceFields method requires the naming convention to be followed. I.e.

```
 public class MyForm extends VerticalLayout {
     // This will match getName/setName in Person
     private TextField name = new TextField("Name");
 }

 ...
 MyForm myForm = new MyForm();
 binder.bindInstanceFields(myForm);
```

Note, that `bindInstanceFields` will bind the fields you did not manually configure with `binder.forField(..)`, not override them.

Second, The `BeanValidationBinder` is a variant of Binder purposed for use with JSR-303 validation annotations in your entities.

```
Binder<Person> binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>();
```

Note, as `bindInstanceFields` wont override existing bindings, if you use `binder.forField(..)` with `BeanValidationBinder` with some `withValidator`, none of the existing JSR-303 annottations on the same property will be used.

If you are not using JSR-303 validation annotations, you should use regular `Binder` instead

```
Binder<Person> binder = new Binder<>();
```